# Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app: Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]

Tags: jsp, glassfish-4

I am trying to deploy an war file in glassfish-4 and it seems that it has an error. I tried to check the server log and here is the result.

This is what is in the server log:

```
Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]
at org.glassfish.web.deployment.node.ServletMappingNode.setElementValue(ServletMappingNode.java:114)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.endElement(SaxParserHandler.java:583)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:245)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:665)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:391)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:198)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:222)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:878)
```

What do you think triggered the error?